# c++ static library import to XCode Cocoa project

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode5

I'm very new at Objective-C programming, I have a MacOSX project, with a simple UI code. It has a login function.

I have a .a extension c++11 static library, with two public headers. One includes . I d like to import the library with the headers to my project. It makes the login to my server.

I made a c++ static library target to the code, and imported the needed files, set the c++ flags (stdlib=libstdc++ and -std=c++11) and added gcc49 to search paths. But I get file not found exception to #include  in my c++ header.

Have somebody a good tutorial how to solve my problem?

Comment: So you are developing the C++ static library?  Why `gcc49` and not `clang`?

Comment: If I know well, Clang does not contains all c++11 headers, I'm compiling with clang, but I need some headers (atomic, mutex, ...) that I didn't found at XCode Clang directory. At I read in this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136128/clang-doesnt-know-stdatomic-bool-but-xcode-does) question, clang does not support these c++11 variables. and according to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308167/when-enabling-c11-with-stdlibc-4-7-clang-error-out-while-gcc-compiles-fine) I have to include gcc, the latest stable version I could download from MacPorts is gcc49